# Run a function without a parameter but needed a variable outside of the function - PHP

Tags: php

I have this class called `Campaign` and I'm trying to `echo $campaign->getName()` without using any parameters like `echo $campaign->getName($user_id, $campaign_id)`

```
<?php 

$campaign = new Campaign($db);

class Campaign {

    private $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getName() {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT name FROM campaign WHERE campaign_id = :campaign_id AND user_id = :user_id");
        $status = $query->execute(array(':campaign_id' => $campaign_id, ':user_id' => $user_id));
        return ($query->rowCount() == 1) ? $query->fetchObject()->name : false;
    }
}
```

What I'm getting is

```
Missing argument 1 for Campaign::getName()
Missing argument 2 for Campaign::getName()
```

Well logically thinking that's supposed to happen.

What I'm trying to call is `$user_id and $campaign_id` that's been retrieved at **session**

Here's the structure of my `init.php` where all the classes/functions are being stored.

[image]

Is it possible to call a function without a parameter, but that function needed a variable outside of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access that variable since its only not defined locally inside the function.
If you want to use the var inside when its defined outside you use  `global` before the var.

```
$foo = 'bar';
function baz() {
    global $foo;
    // now u can use it inside.
}
```

[Php variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

I dont like globals personally, you could also do something like:

```
function foo($arg1 = null, $arg2 = null) {
    // if they are not set retrieve from a session
    $arg1 = ($arg1 !== null) ? $arg1 : $_SESSION['arg1'];
   // rinse repeat.
}
```

Comment: Will try this one, will give a feedback on results.

Comment: Added a link to the php variable scope reference.

Comment: By any chance, it's not possible to create function foo(arg1 = $_SESSION['user_id'], arg2 = $_SESSION['campaign_id']) ? Do I have to assign a variable like that on every function that I will make?

Comment: Im not sure actually, try it? :)

Answer (score -1):

You havent called the $user_id and $campaign_id from session

Should have $user_id and $campaign_id as global variables:

```
global $user_id;
global $campaign_id;
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$campaign_id = $_SESSION['campaign_id'];
```

Place the above variable declaration after session_start() on your screenshot

Try this:

```
<?php 

session_start();

$campaign = new Campaign($db);

class Campaign {

    private $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getName() {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT name FROM campaign WHERE campaign_id = :campaign_id AND user_id = :user_id");
        $status = $query->execute(array(':campaign_id' => $_SESSION['campaign_id'], ':user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']));
        return ($query->rowCount() == 1) ? $query->fetchObject()->name : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, umm.. the session_start(); is already applied to my init.php where all the functions are stored and being echoed in all pages.

Comment: you need to have user_id and campaign_id as global variables. Edited my answer to show how!

Comment: It's being returned as null though.

Comment: This is because `require "functions/campaign.php"` is called before you have assigned the values to $user_id and $campaign_id. You should assign values to the variables first and then call the require statement. I would suggest you to move the assignment code below the global declaration of the variables. That should work. Edited my answer to show how